# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `image_url' for nil:NilClass when doing integration test with rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I am a beginner in rails and I am trying to test my rails app

My page works fine but when doing the integration tests, I get this error

```
User signs in with username
     Failure/Error: <div class="art-img" style="background: url(<%= @article.image_url %>); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center">
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `image_url' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the view template with the error **app/view/home/index**

```
  <div class="main-art-con">
    <div class="art-img" style="background: url(<%= @article.image_url %>); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center">
      <div class="content-con">
        <h5 class="art-head"><%= @article.title %></h5>
        <p class="art-con">
          <%= truncate(@article.text, length: 100) %>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my home controller containing the object instance

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @featured_article = Article.unscoped.order(cached_weighted_total: :desc).limit(1)
    @article = @featured_article.last
    @categories = Category.all.ordered_by_priority
  end
end
```

Code for the test

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'User signs in' do
  background do
    User.create(name: 'Jane Doe', username: 'jodi')
  end

  scenario 'with username' do
    visit login_path

    fill_in 'Username', with: 'jodi'


    click_on 'Log in'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Log Out'
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems there is no article present. Can you please share us the code for test ?

Comment: Hey @Didymus Orotayo I think you can do this: `@article = Article.unscoped.order(cached_weighted_total: :desc).limit(1)` in controller. This will return 1 record if any. Reference: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `` undefined method `image_url' for nil:NilClass `` would seem to indicate that `@article` is `nil` in the *test* environment. This environment is distinct from the *development* environment, and the development environment and its class objects are presumably what you see in your browser.

I expect you can fix your problem by creating (at least) one article *in the test environment* before running the test:

```
  background do
    User.create(name: 'Jane Doe', username: 'jodi')
    Article.create(title: 'Your Title', etc...)
  end
```

Then this article will persist in the *test* database, in the same manner as user Jane Doe persists.

As an aside, it also seems that your feature test is implicitly testing (at least) two features of the index: the presence of an image associated with the article, and the presence of the Log Out button. If possible, consider separating these two tests, or at least explicitly testing for both.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this insight